# CheckBox em Angular

Tags: angularjs

Boa noite, pessoal, sou iniciante no desenvolvimento de apps usando Angular, e atualmente, me deparei com a seguinte situação: Eu preciso cadastrar um determinado motorista, o mesmo possui categorias na CNH, eu entao, decidi fazer uma checkbox com os valores (A,B,C,D). Porém, independentemente de eu selecionar a checkbox ou nao, ela vai como true pro meu serviço (REST usando jersey). No meu método insert, eu declaro o array das checkbox e, já coloco os valores true como default, acho que estou errando neste ponto. Como fazer para declarar um array de chckbox pertencendo ao meu objeto motorista fora dessa função? Dese já agradeço!

minha view:

```
<div ng-app="Motorista" ng-controller="motoristaController as vm">
<fieldset>
                      <legend> Categoria CNH </legend>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value1" />A
                      </br>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value2" />B
                      </br>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value3" />C
                      </br>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value4" />D
                      </br>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value5" />E
                      </br>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" ng-click="vm.inserir()" value="Inserir"/>
</div>
```

meu controller:

```
var linkservice = "http://localhost:8080/Cast_Frotas/rest/motorista/";

var app = angular.module('Motorista',[]);

app.controller('motoristaController', function ($scope, $http) {

      //vm.inserir = inserir;

      iniciar();

      function iniciar() {
        this.motorista = {};
        this.motorista.categoria_cnh = {
            value1 : true,
            value2 : true,
            value3 : true,
            value4 : true,
            value5 : true
        };
      }

//PEGANDO ITENS DA SESSION STORAGE
/*var motorista = window.localStorage.getItem('motorista');
$scope.motorista = JSON.parse(motorista);*/

$http.get(linkservice + "select").then(function (response) {    
    $scope.registros = response.data;
});

$http.get(linkservice + "selectPrestador").then(function (response) {
    $scope.prestadores = response.data;
});

$http.get(linkservice + "selectCurso").then(function (response) {
    $scope.cursos = response.data;
});

$scope.inserir = function (){

        alert(this.motorista.categoria_cnh);

    $scope.jsonObj = angular.toJson($scope.motorista, false);
}
});
```

Comment: Pra que essa volta toda pra salvar?

Comment: então, eu mando o objeto (Json) pro meu serviço, foi esse o padrão que determinaram no projeto, @sorack

Comment: Mas as checkbox vao sempre como true, nao sei mexer direito com Angular :(

Comment: Já vi qual foi o seu problema. Você quer umas dicas pra melhorar isso aí também ou só a solução?

Comment: @Sorack, se puder me mandar os dois, ficarei muito agradecido

Comment: Na parte do melhoramento, poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código tem vários problemas:

- A referencia do campo no seu HTML está como `categoria_cnh.value1` quando esses atributos pertenceriam ao motorista, então o correto seria `motorista.categoria_cnh.value1`;
- Está utilizando a `categoria_cnh` como um `array` quando na verdade deveria ser um objeto, então não tem necessidade de usar `[]`, apenas `{}`;
- Falou usar o `=` para atribuir valor. Exemplo: `vm.motorista.categoria_cnh = {...};`;
- Você está atribuindo os valores dentro da função `incluir`, então toda vez que você chama essa função, está sobrescrevendo os valores;

Agora uma dica, dê uma estudada no [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), que convém apenas citar, já que não tem ligação direta com a pergunta. Eu reescrevi seu código utilizando todas essas dicas:

```js
angular
  .module('meuApp', []);

angular
  .module('meuApp')
  .controller('MeuController', MeuController);

MeuController.$inject = [];

function MeuController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.inserir = inserir;

  iniciar();
  
  function iniciar() {
    vm.motorista = {};
    vm.motorista.categoria_cnh = {
        value1 : true,
        value2 : true,
        value3 : true,
        value4 : true,
        value5 : true
    };
  }

  function inserir() {
    console.log(vm.motorista);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meuApp">
  <div ng-controller="MeuController as vm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Categoria CNH </legend>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value1" />A
      </br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value2" />B
      </br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value3" />C
      </br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value4" />D
      </br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.motorista.categoria_cnh.value5" />E
      </br>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" ng-click="vm.inserir()" value="Inserir"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: primeiramente, obrigado por responder. Eu refiz o meu código, editei a pergunta com o código atualizado, no momento que eu clico no botao e ele dispara a função inserir, o Angular lança o seguinte erro no console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoria_cnh' of undefined
    at b.$scope.inserir (controller_motorista.js:40)... O que poderia ser?

Comment: Tenta não usar o this direto. Faz com VM que nem no meu exemplo. Ou usa só  $scope

Comment: Ah, faltou eu dizer que eu tenho mais dados para o motorista, eu acesso os mesmo através do $scope.motorista

Comment: entendi, vou tentar aqui, já posto se deu certo

Comment: Quase certo, o problema agora, é que como eu fiz aquele vm.motorista = {}, a minha variável (objeto) $scope.motorista fica undefined, dessa forma, nao consigo acessar os outros atributos, ex: $scope.motorista.nome, $scope.motorista.celular etc ...